# Can not build project cocos2dx win32

Tags: cocos2d-x

I created 1 project cocos2dx ,after i add 2 file MainMenuSence.h , MainMenuSence.cpp and delete 2 file HelloWorld.h and HelloWorld.cpp . After i changed file Menu2.vcxproj.filters ,so that it look like the following : After . i saved all and build it , but i get error . 
Please help me . :(( . Sorry for my bad english .

```
 <ItemGroup>
<ClCompile Include="main.cpp">
  <Filter>win32</Filter>
</ClCompile>
<ClCompile Include="..\Classes\AppDelegate.cpp">
  <Filter>src</Filter>
</ClCompile>
<ClCompile Include="..\Classes\MainMenuSence.cpp">
  <Filter>src</Filter>
</ClCompile>
```

i get error : Can not open file :..\Classes\HelloWorldSence.cpp no such file or directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Steps can solve your problem-

1) Delete obj , assets , gen and bin folder.

2) Change HelloWorld to MainMenuScene from AppDelegate.